# How to filter failed successful excel upload using EPPlus package in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, angular, excel, asp.net-core-webapi, epplus

I am implementing Excel upload for Employees Leave applications using an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API as the backend and Angular 14 as the frontend.

In ASP.NET Core, I am using Entity Framework and a package called EPPlus.

In the ASP.NET Core Web API backend, I have this model:

```
public class EmployeeLeave
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LeaveStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LeaveEndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then this controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public IActionResult UploadEmployeeLeave([FromForm] ExcelFileUploadModel model)
{
    if (model.File == null || model.File.Length == 0)
    {
        return BadRequest("No file uploaded.");
    }

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(model.File.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
        List<EmployeeLeave> employeeLeaves = new List<EmployeeLeave>();
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();

        // Skip the header row and start reading from the second row
        int startRow = 2;
        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;

        for (int row = startRow; row <= rowCount; row++)
        {
            EmployeeLeave employeeLeave = new EmployeeLeave();
            employeeLeave.EmployeeId = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value?.ToString();
            employeeLeave.EmployeeName = worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value?.ToString();

            if (!DateTime.TryParse(worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value?.ToString(), out DateTime leaveStartDate))
            {
                errors.Add($"Invalid leave start date in row {row}.");
            }
            else
            {
                employeeLeave.LeaveStartDate = leaveStartDate;
            }

            if (!DateTime.TryParse(worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value?.ToString(), out DateTime leaveEndDate))
            {
                errors.Add($"Invalid leave end date in row {row}.");
            }
            else
            {
                employeeLeave.LeaveEndDate = leaveEndDate;
            }

            if (employeeLeave.LeaveStartDate != DateTime.MinValue && employeeLeave.LeaveEndDate != DateTime.MinValue &&
                employeeLeave.LeaveEndDate < employeeLeave.LeaveStartDate)
            {
                errors.Add($"Leave end date cannot be earlier than the leave start date in row {row}.");
            }

            employeeLeaves.Add(employeeLeave);
        }

        if (errors.Any())
        {
            return BadRequest(errors);
        }

        return Ok("Employee leave data uploaded successfully.");
    }
}
```

In the Angular frontend, I have:

**Component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.css']
})
export class FileUploadComponent {
  selectedFile: File | null = null;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  onFileSelected(event: any) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0] as File;
  }

  onUpload() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.selectedFile as Blob);

    this.http.post('https://localhost:5001/api/UploadEmployeeLeave', formData)
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          console.log('File uploaded successfully');
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('Error uploading file:', error);
        }
      );
  }
}
```

**component.html:**

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
<button (click)="onUpload()">Upload</button>
```

Users can upload Leaves Applications of several employees at the same time.

I want the application to be able to upload and save the successful ones into the database. Then display the successful one and also the failed ones with the reason for the failures.

How do I achieve these?